# Create and publish a reusable React Native UI component library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a component library (similar like Kitten UI, Ant design RN and etc) for React Native and I'm wondering if there is any simple example repo or boilerplate (with Typescript) for that? Not including/bridging any native modules but just React Native UI components.